# Does the VSCode extension API offer a a way to access other VSCode windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I had an idea for a Visual Studio Code extension.

Something else I'm working on is the same project in about a dozen programming languages to help me learn them. I thought it would be handy to have a command to pick one at random when I finish something on one and want to switch to one of the others.

That seemed like a fun and simple project to write myself and learn vscode extension coding.

But I can't seem to find any APIs that do any of these things:

- Return a list of open vscode windows.
- Return the number of vscode windoss.
- Go to another vscode window.

By "window" I mean actual separate instances of VSCode. I don't mean the tabs within a single instance. I want to access the list that drops down from the "Window" menu of the app or that is accessible from the command palette using Control-W (on the macOS bindings at least)

Am I missing something? Is the API just a lot tinier than I expected? Are such things specifically not available for security reasons?

AI code bots suggest things like this that access the splits in the current tab of the current window only:

```
    const openWindows = vscode.window.visibleTextEditors.map(editor => editor.viewColumn);
    console.log("Open Windows: ", openWindows);
    
    const openTabs = vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.viewColumn;
    console.log("Open Tabs: ", openTabs);
```

Googling, I don't even find anybody asking about such things, no QA's, no feature requests...